# How to draw pdf content in flutter canvas

Tags: flutter, pdf, canvas, dart-pdf

I'm using Flutter with `pdf` package. In the readme it says use `printing` to show pdf in app.

However, I want to draw in front of the pdf content(taking notes/make annotations). So I guess I have to draw pdf content in my `CustomPaint` widget to get more control to it.

I searched around and didn't found any useful experience. Please let me know it my approach is correct/reasonable and if there's any better approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the part of the README you're talking about is this one :

> Use the printing package https://pub.dev/packages/printing for full
> flutter print and share operation.

This printing package is meant for printing to a real printer.
The pdf package you're using is only meant for creating a pdf in a flutter application, not for displaying it as a widget.

What you want to achieve is to display a pdf and annote on top of it. Your approach is a correct one:

- Use a CustomPainter
- Add a PDF widget as its child
- Paint your annotations on the foreground painter.

To display a pdf as a widget you'll need another package like `advance_pdf_viewer`.

Painting on the foreground painter is important because as stated in the CustomPaint class documentation:

> When asked to paint, CustomPaint first asks its painter to paint on
> the current canvas, then it paints its child, and then, after painting
> its child, it asks its foregroundPainter to paint.

The code should look like :

```
PDFDocument doc = await PDFDocument.fromAsset('assets/test.pdf');

return CustomPaint(
  child: PDFViewer(doc: document)),
  foregroundPainter: AnnotationsPainter(),
);
```